# Spring: add Spring instrument as an library rather than javaagent

Tags: spring, eclipselink, javaagents

I have Spring project with Eclipse Link, and I am trying to convert it to Gradle. But for some reason JVM parameter "-javaagent:~/instrument.jar" is not passed to the container. Is it possible to pass Spring instrument as an library, not as an javaagent?

Comment: Of course it's possible to add it as library. But it won't work. How do you want to pass the JVM parameter to the container and how is Gradle involved? Gradle is a build tool, it doesn't handle container runtimes.